# GCM send message from one device to other without any third part server

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send messages from device to device, without the use of any third part server(Well I do use it for some other parts).
I am using HTTP request to send it to gcm server directly from device.

Heres what I have done.

```
    try {
        HttpPost httppost;
        try {
            httppost = new HttpPost(
                    "https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

        httppost.setHeader("Authorization", "key=512218918480");
        httppost.setHeader("Content-Type",
                "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        postParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("registration_id", id));
        postParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data.mode",
                "exampleContentOfYourMessage"));
        postParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("m",
                "exampleContentOfYourMessage"));
        HttpResponse response;
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpEntity entity;
        try {
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParams, "utf-8"));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        try {
            response = httpClient.execute(httppost);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        entity = response.getEntity();
        if (entity != null
                && response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
            return true;
        } else {
            Log.e("Tag", "No Connection");
            return false;
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("grokkingandroid",
                "IOException while sending registration id", e);
    }
    return false;

}
```

This returns

```
 02-24 00:19:13.772: W/DefaultRequestDirector(9913): Authentication error: Unable to respond to any of these challenges: {}
```

So it looks like authentication error for https . DO I need to send something more to gcm server?

I also know the flaws for using this method.My id would be in app so less security.I cant send much data and so on.

Comment: In the Authorization header, you must put your alphanumeric API key, not the 12-digit project ID/sender ID that you had placed. How will you get the client device registration IDs, though?

Comment: Yeah got it..I did realize my mistake soon after posting the question. I plan to sync regids from my server with a polling service. I plan to send the message directly as I think it will decrease the send time as my server is eliminated. Am I right??